# Click on element by class + offset?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to click the upvote reddit icon here:

http://reddit.com/r/nfl/comments/3ssu1v/the_2015_cardinals_are_on_their_way_to_becoming/cx02unv

I've used the `javascript:document.getElementById("#ID").click();` but the element doesn't have an ID.

So I set it to `javascript:document.getElementsByClassName("arrow up login-required access-required").click();`

Now if you view the page, there are multiple voting sections so you need offset, but I can't figure out how to combine the two together.

I tried looking at the following resources, but I cannot understand them:

- http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/css_offset.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nodelist_length.asp

Answer (score -1):

## Disclaimer:

I don't recommend creating bots to auto-upvote on reddit, as it is against their Terms and Conditions. This answer is for educational purposes **only**. Use this answer at your own risk.

---

Trying to judge by CSS offset makes no sense: you'll get multiple comments in random orders.

Luckily, the reddit comment has an id (open your browser's dev tools): `#thing_t1_cx02unv`. As the up vote button is a direct child of the post. To avoid getting all of the up vote buttons contained in comments on the comment, you can use the JQuery child `>` selector, which only selects direct children.

You could try using vanilla Javascript, but complex queries are best handled with [JQuery](http://jquery.com).

The voting buttons are wrapped in `midcol`, and the up arrow has a class of  `.arrow.up`, so this selector can be used:

```
$(".arrow.up > .midcol > #thing_t1_cx02unv")
```

To click:

```
$(".arrow.up > .midcol > #thing_t1_cx02unv").click()
```

Answer (score -1):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a nodelist and not a node. So you need to identify which item you want to use.

You should use the `[index]` syntax.

So `document.getElementsByClassName("arrow up login-required access-required")[0].click();` would fire on the first arrow.